# Limits of a recursively defined sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

Let $x_1=a$ and define a sequence $\left(x_n\right)$ recursively by:
$x_{n+1} = \dfrac{x_n}{1 + \frac{x_n}{2}}$

For what values of $a$ is it true that $x_n$ approaches $0$?

Comment: would it be something like L = L/(1+L/2) ?

Comment: Actually, what is a/the general policy about such questions?

Comment: If you mean questions not written with LaTeX, it is universally considered reasonable to edit the question to add mathematical typesetting.  If you mean editing to change mathematical aspects of the question, I don't know.  If you mean "pure problem statement" questions this is a subject of discussion and disagreement in the meta.MSE site, and opinion has shifted back and forth.  There is no general policy of any kind as to what individual users should do with the answer/comment/edit/vote capabilities in relation to a question. @wlod

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what @wlod is asking either, but if it pertains to the deleted answer: I'm not sure if you have enough rep to edit a question. If you do, you can edit the question to the best of your ability (adding latex and keeping the content as close as possible to whatever was intended), and not by submitting an answer (there is an edit button immediately below the question text). I know for certain that, if you have low reputation, your edit will be placed in a queue until someone confirms it is a reasonable edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever the sequence converges (to $L$, say) we must have $L=\frac L{1+\frac L2}$, i.e. $L=0$. So the question is just: For which $a$ does the sequence converge?

If $a>0$ then by induction all $x_n>0$ so that the sequence is strictly decreasing and bounded from below, hence convergent.

If $a=0$ the sequence is constant, hence also convergent.

If $a<-2$ then $x_2>0$ and the sequence converges as in the case $a=x_2>0$.

If $a=-2$ the recursion fails to define $x_2$, i.e. we don ont even have a sequence.

If $-2<a<0$, the sequence starts decreasing as long as $-2<x_n<0$. It cannot remain bounded from below by $-2$ as otherwise it would converge to some number on $[-2,0)$, which is impossible. Thus after finitely many steps we obtain some $x_n<-2$ and from then on convergence as shown above. Or we hit $-2$ exactly and the recursion fails.
To see for which $a$ we hit $-2$, solve the recursion for $x_n$:
$$ x_n = \frac{2x_{n+1}}{1-x_{n+1}}.$$
Consider the sequence $y_n$ given by $y_1=2$ and $y_{n+1}=\frac{2y_n}{1+y_n}$. If and only if $-a=y_n$ for some $n$, our original sequence will hit $-2$ (for we see that $x_k=-y_{n+1-k}$ for $1\le k\le n$).
One readily shows that $y_n=\frac{2^n}{2^n-1}$.

**Summary:**
If $a=-\frac{2^n}{2^n-1}$ for some $n$, the sequence is only finite.
In all other cases it converges to $0$.